# Indy 10 SSL root certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, delphi-xe2, indy

I am trying to verify server certificate. I use Indy 10 and OpenSSL. I specify Root `RootCertFile` and `VerifyDepth` to `MaxInt`. OnVerifyPeer works fine - `AOk` is `true`. I wonder how to load certificates from **Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities**. There is my stripped code of a client:

```
uses
  {Delphi}
  IdSSLOpenSSL
  , IdHTTP
  , IdHeaderList
  , System.Classes
  {Project}
  ;

type
  TUnicodeHTTPPoster = class
  strict private
    FidHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    FLastError: string;
    FCertPassword: string;

    procedure OnGetPassword(var Password: string);
    function OnVerifySSLPeer(Certificate: TIdX509;AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(const ASSLVersion: TIdSSLVersion; const AAccept: string = 'application/xml';
      const ACharSet: string = 'utf-8'; const ACertFile: string = ''; const AKeyFile: string = '';
      const ACertPassword: string = ''); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function Post(const ACustomHeaders: TIdHeaderList; const ARawBody: TStream;
      const AURL: string; out AResponse: string): integer;
  end;

implementation

uses
  {Delphi}
  System.SysUtils
  , IdURI
  , IdGlobal
  {Project}
  ;

constructor TUnicodeHTTPPoster.Create(const ASSLVersion: TIdSSLVersion; const AAccept: string = 'application/xml';
  const ACharSet: string = 'utf-8'; const ACertFile: string = ''; const AKeyFile: string = '';
  const ACertPassword: string = '');
var
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  inherited Create;

  FidHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  FidHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/xml';
  if AAccept <> '' then
    FidHTTP.Request.Accept := AAccept;

  FidHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
  if ACharSet <> '' then
    FidHTTP.Request.Charset := ACharSet;

  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(FidHTTP);

  if FileExists(ACertFile) then
    _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile := ACertFile;

  if FileExists(AKeyFile) then
    _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile := AKeyFile;

  FCertPassword := ACertPassword;

  FidHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method := ASSLVersion;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnGetPassword := OnGetPassword;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := MaxInt;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer := OnVerifySSLPeer;
  _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'C:\Users\ekolesnikovics\Desktop\Projects\nDentity\ndentify\Build\dc_ofisas.nsoft.lt.pem';
  FidHTTP.IOHandler := _IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
end;

function TUnicodeHTTPPoster.OnVerifySSLPeer(Certificate: TIdX509;AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AOk;
end;

procedure TUnicodeHTTPPoster.OnGetPassword(var Password: string);
begin
  Password := FCertPassword;
end;

function TUnicodeHTTPPoster.Post(const ACustomHeaders: TIdHeaderList; const ARawBody: TStream;
  const AURL: string; out AResponse: string): integer;
var
  _URL: string;
  _ResponseStream: TStringStream;
begin
  Result := 500;
  FLastError := '';

  try
    if Trim(AURL) = '' then
      raise EArgumentException.Create('URL is not provided.');

    _URL := TIdURI.URLEncode(AURL, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    _ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      if Assigned(FidHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders) then
        FidHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;

      if Assigned(ACustomHeaders) then
        FidHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders := ACustomHeaders;

      FidHTTP.Post(_URL, ARawBody, _ResponseStream);
      _ResponseStream.Position := 0;
      AResponse := _ResponseStream.DataString;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(_ResponseStream);
    end;

    Result := 200;
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      Result := E.ErrorCode;
      FLastError := E.ErrorMessage;
      FidHTTP.Disconnect;
    end;

    on E: Exception do
    begin
      FLastError := E.Message;
      FidHTTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "*I wonder how to load certificates from Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities*" - OpenSSL does not support Windows' certificate stores, only its own store. So, you would have to export the Windows certificates and import them into OpenSSL. It can be done, but it is not trivial. Indy does not expose functionality to do that for you, you would have to use the OpenSSL API directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using free https://github.com/magicxor/WinCryptographyAPIs

```
procedure TUnicodeHTTPPoster.ExportWindowsCertificateStoreToFile(const ACertFile: string);
var
  _hStore: HCERTSTORE;
  _CertContext: PCertContext;
  _pchString: Cardinal;
  _szString: string;
  _CertList: TStringList;
begin
  _hStore := CertOpenSystemStore(0, PChar('ROOT'));
  if (_hStore = nil) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  _CertList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    _CertContext := CertEnumCertificatesInStore(_hStore, nil);
    if (_CertContext = nil) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    while _CertContext <> nil do
    begin
      _pchString := 0;
      if not CryptBinaryToString(_CertContext.pbCertEncoded,
        _CertContext.cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, nil, _pchString) then
        RaiseLastOSError;

      SetLength(_szString, 0);
      SetLength(_szString, _pchString - 1);
      if not CryptBinaryToString(_CertContext.pbCertEncoded,
        _CertContext.cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, PWideChar(_szString),
        _pchString) then
        RaiseLastOSError;

      _CertList.Add('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----');
      _CertList.Add(Trim(StrPas(PWideChar(_szString))));
      _CertList.Add('-----END CERTIFICATE-----');

      _CertContext := CertEnumCertificatesInStore(_hStore, _CertContext);
    end;

    _CertList.SaveToFile(ACertFile);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_CertList);
    CertCloseStore(_hStore, 0);
  end;
end;

_RootCertFileName := TPath.Combine(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), 'windows_cert.pem');
ExportWindowsCertificateStoreToFile(_RootCertFileName);
_IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := _RootCertFileName;
```